# Format URL query "example [{u'1438923522000': 98}]"

Tags: json, python-3.x, split, save

```
`import json
 import urllib2
 response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.energyhive.com/mobile_proxy/getCurrentVa$
 content = response.read()

 for x in json.loads(content):
    if x["cid"] == "PWER":
        print(x["data"])
```

`

Hi all, I have some code that I require part of the code sent to a **txt file**, example `[{u'1438923522000': 98}]`, after running code, I just need the txt after : save as txt, or better sql.

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: get reply **[{u'1438923522000': 98}]** , the number after the : is a result in watts. i would like the responds to say xxxx  example   98   .

Comment: You can't run this code, as it's syntactically invalid as currently written. How should the `urlopn()` call finish, please?

Comment: full code with api url is

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env python  
    import urllib2  
    import json  
    api_key = 'VtxgIC2UnhfUmXe_pBksov7-lguAQMZD'  
    url = 'http://www.energyhive.com/mobile_proxy/getCurrentValuesSummary?token='+api_key  
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)  
    content = response.read()  
    for x in json.loads(content):  
        if x["cid"] == "PWER":  
            print (x["data"])    
            
    for y in json.loads(content):  
        if y["cid"] == "PWER_GAC":  
            print(y["data"])

Answer (score 0):

If `x["data"] == [{u'1438923522000': 98}]` then `x["data"][0] == {u'1438923522000': 98}`. If you can guarantee that the dict will only have one key (as your example does) then the expression you are looking for is something like

```
next(x["data"][0].values())
```

Since you appear to be using Python 3, `dict.values()` is a generator, so calling `next()` on it gives you the first value without needing to know what the associated key is.

Comment: i know i posted it again below with the updated code with api, no idea how to put youre code in i will delete the above.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
import urllib2  
import json  
api_key = 'VtxgIC2UnhfUmXe_pBksov7-lguAQMZD'  
url = 'http://www.energyhive.com/mobile_proxy/getCurrentValuesSummary?token='+api_key  
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)  
content = response.read()  
for x in json.loads(content):  
    if x["cid"] == "PWER":  
        print (x["data"])    

for y in json.loads(content):  
    if y["cid"] == "PWER_GAC":  
        print(y["data"])
```

when i load this code i get
[{u'1439087809000': 36}]
[{u'1439087809000': 0}]
i would like to delete everything apart from the results
36
0
updated api to run code